# Parse not upload deviceToken for iOS7

Tags: ios, parse-platform

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[@"global"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

    [PFPush subscribeToChannelInBackground:@"" block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
           NSLog(@"Successfully subscribed to broadcast channel!");
        } else {
           NSLog(@"Failed to subscribe to broadcast channel; Error: %@",error);
        }
    }];
}
```

When testing my app on an iOS8 or iOS9 device,it runs successfully,but on iOS7,error occurs:

Failed to subscribe to broadcast channel; Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x1654f140 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

By the way, deviceToken has received.

Parse version is 1.9.0, Xcode version is 7.0.1, iOS version is 7.1.2

Comment: I think I may be having a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160713/cocoa-error-3840-parse-code-ios7-only

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33189580/4062250

Comment: Just waiting for the next SDK