# Cocoa error 3840 Parse Code iOS7 only

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, parse-platform, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk

**Background:** I decided a couple days ago that I was going to update Facebook SDK to FBSDKCoreKit from Facebook-iOS-SDK v3.24. I updated my Podfile accordingly and installed all libraries fine. I then began updating some of the code to work with the updated SDK spec.

After working on it for a short amount of time, I changed my mind and decided to rollback to the old version.  I made all necessary cocoapods changes and installs, discarded all local changes in Xcode, recompiled and ran. Everything worked fine... or so I thought.

**The Problem:** Now, when I try to run on my old iOS7 test device, I get an error whenever the app launches.  Below is the exact console output:

```
2015-10-15 20:14:31.271 hiatus[184:6003] [Error]: Failed to run command eventually with 
error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object
and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x14d67d20 {NSDebugDescription=
JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

After this error is displayed in the console, no Parse functionality works. Which means, in my case, that a user is unable to login. An empty error is displayed instead.

Everything works fine on iOS8, and iOS9 (simulators and real devices). I'm working with Parse v1.9. I've tried cleaning the project, resetting, etc, but without any success.

I've been able to track this down to a specific function within PFEventuallyQueue.m.  It seems to occur within `(void)_runCommandsWithRetriesCount:`.  I just have no way of knowing how to fix it.

Comment: I have the same problem. Yesterday updated pods (included Parse and Facebook...) and Parse dont parse the JSON received from them in iOS 7. In iOS 8 and iOS 9 there is no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with SDK v1.9.0 (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/388). It has been fixed but not released yet (it will be part of the 1.9.1 release).

You have 3 options :

- Use 1.8.5 until 1.9.1 is released.
- Fix the bug yourself by making this change : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/commit/edde3bfa8a4476ba460dddbef6f75772960e1718
- Use the master branch of the git repository to get the latest commits. If you're using cocoapods you can do it by setting your pod like this : `pod 'Parse', :git => 'https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX.git'`

Answer (score 1):

Now is available Parse 1.9.1 but I recommend using CocoaPods for any Framework: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Parse